# Aggregating json results in python

Tags: python

I have a list imported through json in the form

```
  [{'beer/ABV': 5.0,
  'beer/beerId': '47986',
  'beer/brewerId': '10325',
  'beer/name': 'Sausa Weizen',
   ...
```

that consists of which customers drank which beer and their ratings. I want to calculate the average ratings for each beer. What is the most efficient way to do this in python? I can use numpy or scipy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling your list `beer_json`, and presuming `beer/ABV` is the rating:

```
import numpy as np

beer_ratings = {}
for beer in {beer_info['beer/beerId'] for beer_info in beer_json}:
    ratings = [beer_info['beer/ABV']
               for beer_info in beerjson
               if beer_info['beer/beerId'] == beer]
    beer_ratings[beer] = np.mean(ratings)
```

This iterates over each beer once (using it's `beerId`), then creates a list `ratings` containing only ratings for  that particular beer, and calculates the mean.

I cannot guarantee this is the most efficient way to do this, but since you're using Python I'm guessing efficiency is not the top priority.

Comment: ABV means "alcohol by volume".

Comment: @ChrisJohnson thanks! That's probably a really good number to know

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want (you have to install pandas first of course):

```
import pandas

beers = [
    {'beer/beerId': '789', 'beer/ABV': 5.0, 'beer/name': 'Sausa Weizen'},
    {'beer/beerId': '789', 'beer/ABV': 4.0, 'beer/name': 'Sausa Weizen'},
    {'beer/beerId': '789', 'beer/ABV': 3.0, 'beer/name': 'Sausa Weizen'},
    {'beer/beerId': '123', 'beer/ABV': 1.0, 'beer/name': 'Bud Light'},
    {'beer/beerId': '123', 'beer/ABV': 2.0, 'beer/name': 'Bud Light'}
    ]
df = pandas.DataFrame(beers)
df.groupby(['beer/beerId']).mean()
```